# Pandas simple way to split column header names on separator

Tags: python, pandas

I need to rename columns name in pandas but need the string after pipe symbol `@`.

Example :
`Col1 @ my data1` to `my data1`

I am reading a csv and trying the be

```
df= pandas.read_csv('path');
df.rename(columns=lambda col: col.replace(col, '^[^@\r\n]+@\s*\K.*$'),inplace=True)
```

regex is working independently but with lambda and pandas it just replaces column name with regex text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for rename here, you can just split on your separator symbol and retrieve the last split. This works even if the separator is not present.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('@').str[-1].str.strip()
```

`rename` returns a copy of the dataframe which is unnecessary since you aren't actually making any transformations on the data.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1 @ my data1', 'my data 2'])
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Col1 @ my data1, my data 2]
Index: []
```

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('@').str[-1].str.strip()
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [my data1, my data 2] # <-- 
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

This renames the columns in the DataFrame by only including what comes after the pipe symbol by using a dictionary comprehension

```
df.rename(columns={x: x.split('@ ')[1] 
                   (if '@' in x and not x.endswith('@')) else x 
                   for x in df.columns}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: this return index out of bounds -> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think this problem might be caused by columns ending in '@'. I've updated the code to work with this now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
#example
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Col1 @ my data1", "my data2", "Col3 @ my data3"])

out = df.rename(lambda x: x.split("@")[1].strip() if "@" in x else x, axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out.columns)

#Index(['my data1', 'my data2', 'my data3'], dtype='object')
```